# Is there a rule to prevent infinite games?

Tags: hive

It is possible for player to keep repeating the same moves. Chess has a [Threefold repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threefold_repetition) rule and  [Fifty-move rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifty-move_rule).

Are there similar rules for Hive? If no, how (in the context of tournaments) are the issues those rules are designed to address tackled in Hive? Note, that hive has something called "tournamets rules" (which prohibit placing a bee as one's first move), so I'm assumuing there are tournamets.

I found a similar question being asked [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/90591/infinite-repetition) but no reasonable answer were given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in the [rules](https://www.gen42.com/download/rules/hive/Hive_English_Rules.pdf)

> A draw may be agreed if both players are in a position where they are
>   forced to move the same two pieces over and over again, without any
>   possibility of the stalemate being resolved.